# How can I change @Scheduler cron expression dynamically in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler

I am trying to call an API in specific time.
But sometimes api call can be failed so I made an logic to check when api call has failed.

After confirming the api call failure, I would like to change the @Schedulercron expression from the current cron expression to 15 minutes later.

How can I change cron expression dynamically??

Below is my API call code.

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 9 19 * * *", zone = "Asia/Seoul")
public void callAPi() throws InterruptedException {

    swrList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<GeoInfo> giList = gs.getGeoXY();
    
    for(GeoInfo gi : giList) {
        
        ShortWeatherReq swr = new ShortWeatherReq(APK.getApiKey(),"1",gi.getX(),gi.getY());
        swr.setBaseDate(); //현재 날짜로 baseDate를 설정하는 메소드를 호출
        swr.setNx(gi.getX()); //x좌표값 저장
        swr.setNy(gi.getY()); //y좌표값 저장
        
        swrList.add(swr); //list에 swr 추가
    }
    
    for(GeoInfo gi : giList) {
        
        ShortWeatherReq swr = new ShortWeatherReq(APK.getApiKey(),"2",gi.getX(),gi.getY());
        swr.setBaseDate(); //현재 날짜로 baseDate를 설정하는 메소드를 호출
        swr.setNx(gi.getX()); //x좌표값 저장
        swr.setNy(gi.getY()); //y좌표값 저장
        
        swrList.add(swr); //list에 swr 추가
    }
    
    //위 객체를 가지고 이제 API를 호출할수 있게 Service에게 전해줘야 함
    sws.setSwrList(swrList);
    
    temperList = sws.callSW(); // API 통신 Service 호출
    
    
    //Confirming API call failure

    if(temperList.isEmpty()) { //온도 리스트가 비어있다면 진입
        logger.warn("TemperList is empty");
        //이제 여기서 메일을 보내주는 서비스를 만들어서 메일 전송을 해줘야 함
        ms.sendErrorMail();
        logger.info("-------------------");
        
        logger.info("API Connection Fail");
    }else {
        logger.info("-------------------");
        
        logger.info("API ConnectionSuccess");
        
        logger.info("-------------------");
        
        //List에 담긴 온도 DB에 저장
        for(int i = 0;i<temperList.size();i++) {
            Temperature temp = temperList.get(i);
            ts.saveTemp(temp);
        }
        
        logger.info("DB Store Success");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Spring retry, sleep for 15 minutes, and then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should activate `Spring Retry` on your `App` class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableRetry
public class App {
    // something
}
```

Then you need to add `@Retryable` to your method that you use as `@Scheduled`.

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 9 19 * * *", zone = "Asia/Seoul")
// Add this line
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000), value={ApiCallException.class})
public void callAPi() throws InterruptedException {

    swrList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<GeoInfo> giList = gs.getGeoXY();
    
    for(GeoInfo gi : giList) {
        
        ShortWeatherReq swr = new ShortWeatherReq(APK.getApiKey(),"1",gi.getX(),gi.getY());
        swr.setBaseDate(); //현재 날짜로 baseDate를 설정하는 메소드를 호출
        swr.setNx(gi.getX()); //x좌표값 저장
        swr.setNy(gi.getY()); //y좌표값 저장
        
        swrList.add(swr); //list에 swr 추가
    }
    
    for(GeoInfo gi : giList) {
        
        ShortWeatherReq swr = new ShortWeatherReq(APK.getApiKey(),"2",gi.getX(),gi.getY());
        swr.setBaseDate(); //현재 날짜로 baseDate를 설정하는 메소드를 호출
        swr.setNx(gi.getX()); //x좌표값 저장
        swr.setNy(gi.getY()); //y좌표값 저장
        
        swrList.add(swr); //list에 swr 추가
    }
    
    //위 객체를 가지고 이제 API를 호출할수 있게 Service에게 전해줘야 함
    sws.setSwrList(swrList);
    
    temperList = sws.callSW(); // API 통신 Service 호출
    
    
    //Confirming API call failure

    if(temperList.isEmpty()) { //온도 리스트가 비어있다면 진입
        // Add this line
        throw new ApiCallException("API Connection Fail")
    }else {
        logger.info("-------------------");
        
        logger.info("API ConnectionSuccess");
        
        logger.info("-------------------");
        
        //List에 담긴 온도 DB에 저장
        for(int i = 0;i<temperList.size();i++) {
            Temperature temp = temperList.get(i);
            ts.saveTemp(temp);
        }
        
        logger.info("DB Store Success");
    }
}
```

Here is to set the `backoff` parameter with `@Retryable` annotation to set the next runtime you want. In the `Spring Retry` documentation related to the `BackOffPolicies`, a definition is made as follows.

> When retrying after a transient failure, it often helps to wait a bit before trying again, because usually the failure is caused by some problem that can only be resolved by waiting. If a RetryCallback fails, the RetryTemplate can pause execution according to the BackoffPolicy.

You can find detailed information about `Spring Retry` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/retry.html).

While my answer doesn't provide for dynamically changing cron statements, I hope it will solve your case.